# Other link relationships and impact to the SEO

Tags: seo, search-engines, xhtml

Example other link relationships

```
<head>
<link rel='index' title='Main Title' href='http://domain.com/' />
<link rel='start' title='Part Three' href='http://domain.com/part-3/' />
<link rel='prev' title='Part Two' href='http://domain.com/part-2/' />
<link rel='next' title='Part Four' href='http://domain.com/part-4/' />
</head>
```

Questions

Have a big impact to make my site get a nice rank to Search Engine?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. These tags used this way may help to associate related documents together. If they do have value I would say it is a small amount but definitely worth doing as browsers may also use these tags to help the user navigate the website.